# No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() getting this error while using firebase analytics in next js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-analytics

```
**const analytics = getAnalytics();
    useEffect(() => {
        logEvent(analytics, "page_view", { showScreen });
    }, [showScreen]);**
```

getting error in getAnalytics().

Comment: I think you should pass the initialized firebase `app` to `getAnayltics(app)`

Comment: i was getting error of order of componenets

Comment: is your issue fixed now?

Comment: yes it is fixed by any chance did you create context for Firebase analytics?